# Async Promise not getting the right value

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

```
function getProjects() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    axios.get('url', {
      auth: {
        username: 'username',
        password: '   '
      }
    }).then(function(response) {
      let res = response.data.value;
      for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
        projects.push(res[i])
        resolve(projects);
      }
      console.log(projects)
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error)
    })
  })
}

getProjects()
  .then(function(proj) {
    console.log('proj', proj)

    function asnycItemAssignment() {
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        for (let i = 0; i < proj.length; i++) {
          axios.get(`url`, {
              auth: {
                username: 'username',
                password: '   '
              }
            }).then(function(response) {
              //console.log(response.data.value)
              finalArr.push(response.data.value)
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
              console.log(error)
            })
        }

        resolve(finalArr)
      })
    }

    asnycItemAssignment()
      .then(function(res) {

        console.log('res', res)

        function flatten() {
          return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

            var myNewArray3 = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < res.length; ++i) {
              for (var j = 0; j < res[i].length; ++j) {

                console.log('pushed', i, j, res[i][j])
                myNewArray3.push(res[i][j]);
              }
            }

            console.log('finalArr', myNewArray3)
            resolve(myNewArray3)
          })
        }

        flatten()
          .then(function(value) {
            console.log('val', value)
          })

      })

  })
}
```

Here is what I am trying to do.

I am trying to fetch the list of projects from the API, store it into `projects` and resolve it to the `Promise`. Then again, I try to use the the names of the `projects` and use that for another API that gives me the data inside that project. This will store it into `finalArr`. I resolve `finalArr` this time.

`finalArr` is an array of arrays of objects. Something like `[[{...}{...}][{...}]]` That's why I wanted to flatten to make it like `[{...},{...},{...},{...}]`.

However, in my `asnycItemAssignment`, the `res` which should give me the result of `finalArr` does not give me the full array with all values in it.

The code is quite messy, but I feel like I did it correctly.
What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

```
async function getData() {
  let getProject =
    await axios.get('url', {
      auth: {
        username: 'username',
        password: '    '
      }
    })

  let projects = await getProject.data.value;

  projects.map(project => {
    let ItemAssignment = 
      axios.get(`url`, {
        auth: {
          username: 'username',
          password: '    '
        }
      })

    let values = await ItemAssignment.data.value
    console.log(values)
  })

  console.log('pr', projects)
}

getData()
```

Comment: You have some big problems here -- you are wrapping axios get in  a promise even though it returns a promise and you are calling `resolve` multiple times in a loop. We can fix these but it's not clear what the `asnycItemAssignment` function is doing. You're looping through `proj` but you aren't using the elements in `proj` anywhere. So it's not clear why you're going that.

Comment: You are calling resolve(finalArr) synchronously while you make your 2nd axios calls asynchronously. You must wait for all secondary axios calls to finish before you resolve asyncItemASsignment. Chris' solution will direct you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

I really think you should read up on async/await. It makes code so much more readable when you depend on the result of one async operation to then do another. Some pseudocode is below, in order to get you going:

```
async function go() {
    try {
        const projects = await getProjects();
        projects.map(project => {
            const itemAssignments = await asnycItemAssignment(project);
            const flattened = await flatten(itemAssignments);
            console.log(flattened);
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e); // 
    }
}
```

Also, generically to see how axios can be used:

```
async getData() {
    return await axios(...);
}
```

Then you can use getData, like:

```
const r = await GetData();
```

Comment: Am I supposed to use this instead of `asnycItemAssignment`, or shall I replace both Promises into this?

Comment: It was just a quick way to show how short it *could look*. If you declare a function as "async" then you don't need to refer to a promise at all. The "async" sort of "promisifies" the function - simply return what you need from the function (which is essentially then its resolve) and if you need to reject, you just throw an error - see here: https://javascript.info/async-await

Comment: I am trying this and it truly looks way simpler! Thanks! But if this kind of functionality exists, why and when do we have to use Promises?

Comment: I don't use them at all anymore, but if someone has a good usecase, I'd be glad to hear it.

Comment: Does await/async pretty much do everything that Promise does in a simpler way?

Comment: Yes, it essentially makes things "thenable", allowing you to chain all sorts of things. I haven't had the need for promises since async/await came about.

Comment: Please check my EDIT. I tried some snippets using your example. `console.log('pr', projects)` works for me, but when I do `let values = await ItemAssignment.data.value` it keeps saying `await is a reserved word`. Any idea?

Comment: In order to await a function, it must be declared as an async function. You are awaiting ItemAssignment, but that is not declared async. You can see in the pseudocode I presented, I refer to a function called "asyncItemAsssignment"; the idea would be that is a function that is declared async somewhere else in the code.

Comment: but then how did my `getProject` work if it wasn't stated `async`? The `await getProject.data.value` works but the `await ItemAssignment.data.value` doesn't work although I used the same axios call.

Comment: Ideally for axios (which uses promises) you can put each one into a conventient async function. I will add that function (called getData) to the example, so you can see what I mean.

Comment: what if I want to map the `projects` into axios just as your example?

Comment: Also the editted answer also gives me the `await is a reserved word` error.

Answer (score 0):

One issue with your code is this:

```
  for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
    projects.push(res[i])
    resolve(projects)
  }
```

It almost never makes sense to call a promise's `resolve()` method in a for-loop (or any other looping construct), as you can only meaningfully call it once—or rather, the promise is resolved as soon as you call it the first time. This issue is hidden, in practice, in **this** code because you are modifying `projects` in-place each time you loop through the for-loop, and the for-loop may in-fact complete before you ever use the resolved promise for anything.

Resolving this first issue is as simple as moving `resolve(projects)` a couple lines further down:

```
  for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
    projects.push(res[i])
  }
  console.log(projects)
  resolve(projects)
```

Probably the main issue, though, is when and how you are calling `resolve(finalArr)` in here:

```
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    for (let i = 0; i < proj.length; i++) {     
      axios.get(`url`, {                        
        auth: {                                 
          username: 'username',                 
          password: '   '                       
        }                                       
      }).then(function(response) {              
        //console.log(response.data.value)      
        finalArr.push(response.data.value)      
      })                                        
      .catch(function(error) {                  
        console.log(error)                      
      })                                        
    }                                           

    resolve(finalArr)                           
  })
```

The pushes onto `finalArr` don't happen until after the individual `axios.get` calls resolve, but your call to `resolve(finalArr)` happens (essentially) **immediately** after all the `axios.get` calls are **started**.

Fixing this is a little trickier, as you'll want to wait until ALL the `axios.get` calls finish before resolving. One way to do that is with `Promise.all()`:

```
function asnycItemAssignment() {
  for (let i = 0; i < proj.length; i++) {
    finalArr.push(
      axios.get(`url`, {
        auth: {
          username: 'username',
          password: '   '
        }
      }).then(function(response) {
        return response.data.value
      })
    )
  }
  return Promise.all(finalArr).catch(function(error) { console.log(error) })
}
```

As you admit, the code you have is pretty messy, and I agree with the other answers that you would do well to consider switching to the `await`/`async` syntax.